# put space between concatenate strings

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, string-concatenation

I am searching to concatenate two strings (passed by C) putting the result in a third string. I did it but know i want to put a space between the strings but... It'snt possible..!
This is the C's part

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void concatena(char *stringa, char *stringa2, char *dest);

int main(void)
{
    char stringa[17] = { "stringa numero 1" };
    char stringa2[17] = { "stringa numero 2" };
    char dest[34] = { "" };

    concatena(stringa, stringa2, dest);

    printf("%s", dest);

    getchar();
}
```

that call the masm32's part:

```
.586
.model flat
.code

_concatena proc

;pre
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push ebx
push edi
push esi

;clean
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
xor esi, esi
xor edi, edi


mov eax, dword ptr[ebp+8]           ;source=stringa
mov ebx, dword ptr[ebp+12]          ;target=stringa2
mov ecx, dword ptr[ebp+16]          ;buffer=dest

inizio:
mov dl,byte ptr[eax+esi*1]
cmp dl,0
je space ;first string finished
mov byte ptr[ecx+esi*1], dl
inc esi
jmp inizio

space:
inc esi
mov byte ptr[ecx+esi*1],32
;if i put a 'inc esi' here the result is the same
jmp fine1

fine1:

mov dl, byte ptr[ebx+edi*1]
cmp dl, 0
je fine2 ;second string finished
mov byte ptr[ecx+esi*1], dl
inc edi
inc esi
jmp fine1

fine2:

;post
pop esi
pop edi
pop ebx
pop ebp

ret

;chiusura della procedura
_concatena endp
end
```

when I run it in the output i see:

[image: output]

how you can see concatena() put in the array of destination only the first string...
Thank you very much for every answer!

Comment: If you want a space, add it. If you don't add it, C won't. It's all under your control. With power comes responsibility.

Comment: Start by writing your function in a high level language, *only then* translate it to assembly. The error is your code is going to be quite obvious without the obfuscation.

Comment: Better: `void concatena(const char *stringa, const char *stringa2, char *dest);` and `printf("%s\n", dest);` and maybe add `return 0;` before the closing brace of `main()`

Comment: `char stringa[17] = { "stringa numero 1" };` is an invalid initialiser. Remove the braces.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a `strcat` equivalent that automatically prepends a space before the second string would look something like this:

```
void strcatspace(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *insert_point = &dest[strlen(dest)];
    *insert_point++ = ' ';
    while(*src) *insert_point++ = *src++;
}
```

Haven't tested, but that's the general idea. Translate this function to assembly to achieve the intended result, possibly using a compiler's generated instructions as a starting point.

Comment: I am searching for an assembly solution, so thats why i put on tags "masm", but i dont know why you remove it...
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @AlessandroBarrili Because your question is about "x86" assembly, not about the MASM assembler specifically.

Comment: @AlessandroBarrili You wrote it using *Intel* syntax, which is not specific to MASM.

Answer (score 0):

more proft will be the following code:

```
#include <string.h>

void strcat_space(char* dest, char* src){
    strcat(dest, " ");
    strcat(dest, src);
}
```

enjoy

if you want to pass result to thisrd string, just :

```
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char str1[] = "abcd";
   char str2[] = "efgh";
   char dest[1000];

   strcat_space(strcpy(dest, str1), str2);
   /*
    // or you can also do
        strcat(dest, str1);
        strcat_space(dest, str2);    
   */

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient. For example, it needs to traverse the first string three times (once to copy it to dest, once to add a space, and once after the space). The commented-out alternate option doesn’t work; `dest` isn’t necessarily zeroed out when it’s created in that manner (and if it were, that would be more inefficient). I don’t know why the OP wants an assembly solution, but I doubt an inefficient C solution works.

Comment: How Daniel's say: i am searching an assembly solution... In C i know how to do it!
Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this can be accomplished but generally, I like to simplify as much as possible. A procedure frame isn't really necessary in this case, but because you've included it in your example, I've done the same.

```
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    push    esi
    push    edi

; So second iteration of MoveStr will drop into Done    
    push    Done

    mov     edi, dword ptr [ebp+16]   ; Grab pointer to destination buffer

    mov     esi, dword ptr [ebp+8]    ; Pointer to string 1
    call    MoveStr
    or      al, ' '
    stosb
    mov     esi, dword ptr [ebp+12]

MoveStr:
    lodsb
    or      al, al
    jnz     L1
    ret
L1: stosb
    jmp     MoveStr

Done:
    pop     edi
    pop     esi
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: How would you do it? I am learning to use it so if you can teach me a better procedure... i am here :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlessandroBarrili Better is a relative term as each person will have thier own idea of what better is. In the end, does the algo give you the result your looking for.  Replace your code with this example and then trace through it using a debugger and you'll get a real clear idea how it works.  Learning is simply a matter of knowing the instruction set and then experimenting with code that first of all works and then try to tweak it to improve for space and/or speed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to solve it!
Someone answer/coment here saying that after putting the first string in 'dest' 'esi'(the index) was pointing to an "end of line" or something like that...
So the solution is very very simple, i decrease it and after increase it..!
It's more simple to write it that to explain, I changed only tha label 'space' like that:

```
space:
dec esi ;decrease
inc esi ;increase
mov byte ptr[ecx+esi*1],20h 
inc esi
jmp fine1
```

So thank you everyone!!

Comment: Awesome! You put "downvote" for my answer but NOBODY take me a solution! Maybe its a rude solution but is in asm and work!!